Flutter admob error: This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree
I'm trying to put several ads on the same screen. I am using riverpod and I want to reuse a widget.
When I use that widget twice on the same screen I get this error.Flutter admob error: This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree. If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function with a unique ad object.
Make sure you are not using the same ad object in more than one AdWidget.
final adBannerProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<BannerAd>((ref) async {
  return AdmobPlugin.loadBannerAd();
});

class AdBannerWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AdBannerWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final adBannerAsync = ref.watch(adBannerProvider);

    return adBannerAsync.when(
      data: (bannerAd1) {
        bannerAd1.load();
        return SizedBox(
          width: bannerAd1.size.width.toDouble(),
          height: bannerAd1.size.height.toDouble(),
          child: AdWidget(
            ad: bannerAd1,
          ),
        );
      },
      error: (_, __) => const SizedBox(),
      loading: () => const SizedBox(),
    );
  }
}


I use it here:
    const AdBannerWidget(),
    const AdBannerWidget(),

It gives me this error:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building AdWidget(dirty, state: _AdWidgetState#2f273):
This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree
If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function with a unique ad object.
Make sure you are not using the same ad object in more than one AdWidget.

static class method:
static Future<BannerAd> loadBannerAd({AdSize size = AdSize.banner}) async {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: adBannerId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          print('$ad loaded.');
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('BannerAd failed to load: $err');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    )..load();
  }


try to remove the static keyword
